# How do i query woocommerce booking post type on init action?

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to export `wc_booking` booking details based on  start date on form submit. But the problem is that i cannot get those posts on init action. So is there any other way to query for woocommerce booking post type.

And moreover I am tryin to export these datas on csv. So is ther any possible way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If You have this posts in database You can pass custom query to  `$wpdb`
and get all data that You need. But first:

1. check if data is in database
2. write query that works ( i test that in SQL PRO interface )
3. do not hardcode prefix in query
4. use correct hook (`init` is ok)

than build `csv` file.

Hope it works.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to query for 'wc_booking' (woocommerce booking) post type and it does not query in `init` hook.

Comment: Show me Your code :)